# FLEX: question about dispatching event through hierarchies of components

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

if I dispatch an event from a component, can this event be listened by the grandparent of the component ?

If not, what should I do to make it happen ?

Should I add a listener and dispatcher to the parent (component in the middle) as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for are *bubbling events*. Have a look at the [event propagation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html) chapter in the Flex docs.

What you need is an event that bubbles so you'll need to set the `bubble` attribute to true, see the [docs for the Event constructor](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/events/Event.html#Event()). When you dispatch that event, it will be bubbling up the hierarchy in the third phase of the event propagation and you can listen for it all the way up.

Comment: thanks, now the event dispatched by the children are received from the grandparent. I was wondering if the children can receive the event from the grandparent. (If the bubbling works in the opposite direction). I set bubbling to true, but apparently it doesn't work.

Comment: In order to make it work I've added "stage" stage.addEventListener("UpdateBookmarksEvent", highlightMe);
and now it works. Is this a good practice ? thanks

Comment: Not sure if it is a good practice, because you bind the component, the child, to a certain structure. One approach could be to use a central class that is responsible for this particular piece of business logic. Or have a log at the Mate framework.